# Why do do relative paths in Node.js for FS module and require point at different locations?

Tags: javascript, node.js, path, require, fs

When we run the server on Node JS we should use paths relative to which directory we launched `node` in. To solve this issue we ought to use the `path` module like this:

```js
fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'data', 'someData.csv'))
```

But when we use `require` we can just place a relative path to the file in which we're requiring, wthout having to consider where `node` is launched from:

```
const {data} = require('../../models/data.model');
```

Can you please explain: why does it work that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fs` module handles relative paths relative to the process's working directory, e.g. where it's launched. You can use `process.cwd()` to figure out where that is.

When it comes to `require`, that's a bit of a special case. When your script/module gets initialized and called, NodeJS will under the hood create a brand new `require` function. You can read more about that [here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_id).

Basically, your module has its own `require` which knows of `__dirname` and makes all relative paths passed to it be relative to that path.